# Multiple sub domains are pointing to the same directory as the main domain

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain, godaddy, linode

I have a domain hosted at `Godaddy` adn hosting at `Linode`. I added attached screen shot is my DNS settings. Blue highlighted area is where I put my hosting server's IP
[image]

Now I have 3 sites to be accessed on my server

- domain.store
- admin.domain.store
- operator.domain.store
  My main domain has a **DOT** in it, like domain.store would be my main doamin.

In `Apache`, I created 3 different conf files

- 000-default.conf
- myproj-admin.conf
- myproj-operator.conf

contents of each file is same, (pointed to their respective directories).

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        ServerName www.admin.domain.store

        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.store

        # Change the paths below to the project document root such as /var/www/project1.

        DocumentRoot /var/www/adminProject/public

        <Directory /var/www/adminProject/public>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Set Default Log Paths

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In each configuration file, I have pointed them to their respective directories. I did `a2ensite` and `service apache2 restart` and when I go to my domain and sub-domains, it loads the contents from only the main folder i.e. the directory where the **000-default.conf** is pointed

Answer (score 0):

If Apache httpd cannot match the hostname in the Host: header to a ServerName or ServerAlias in your configuration then it will serve up the contents of the default virtual host. The default virtual host is normally the first one defined.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this? I am not a server guy and I did this with the help of google. How can I correct or check the host:header?

Comment: Nah, I can't be bothered reading the manuals for you. Perhaps you need to read more on how name based virtual hosting works.